# bundling failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir React Native

Tags: react-native, npm

I have no error in my project. But the build not successfully load. see the below image. for more details for error. I am using the below command to run the build `react-native run-android` but the npm failed to create the build. this image directory exists and I give the correct path for images. Thanks in advance.

[image]

-root
--assets
---images
---- All Images here.

`../../assets/images/sky-img.jpg` use this in code.

Comment: Can you please share path of image and how to use it?

Comment: Kindly check your image path. Is it correct?

Comment: it is throwing error for scandir? have you used it anytime? ctrl+shift+f in vscode and search for **scandir** . see if it is written somewhere

Answer (score 12):

Just closing and re-opening the cmd terminal or whatever you are using to run the metro bundler worked for me.

Comment: I believe this works because of @Orel Hassid's answer, resetting the directory...nonetheless, this is what worked for me, so +1!

Answer (score 8):

Just reset the cache of your Metro Bundler with:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

This is happening because the bundler needs to refresh it's existing bundles and the path you previously set.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you run the command from the root directory and not from android directory.

```sh
android> cd..
project> npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```